# PHP foreach get last date for all values

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, foreach

To make it simple here is what I have

1) Array of name :

```
array (size=953)
  0 => string 'name1' (length=5)
  1 => string 'name2' (length=5)
```

2) A foreach from a cursor with mongodb driver :

```
foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {

}
```

Into this foreach I'm looking to get the most recent date for each `name`.
I'm iterating from the most recent date to the most old date and I don't want the loop to continue if I've got the most recent date for each `name`.

So, how could I loop until I've got a date for every name into the array ? There could be a lot of data so I would like to make this loop better than my old solution.

Maybe something like this ?

```
foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {
    if (!in_array($document->color->name, $array)) {
        $position[] = array(
            'name' => $document->color->name,
            'dateTime' => $document->color->dateTime,
        );
    }
    $array[] = $document->color->name;
}
```

**Solution**

```
foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {
    if(!isset($array[$document->color->name])) {
        $position[] = array(
            'name' => $document->color->name,
            'dateTime' => $document->color->dateTime,
        );
    }
    $array[$document->color->name]=true;
}
```

Comment: Code is fine, but better do `$array[$document->color->name]=true;` and `if(!isset($array[$document->color->name]))` bescause it is way faster then in_array() and you will not fill your array with useless dublicates.

Comment: It looks like it's working, thanks a lot. I can't really see the performance change but with thousand of data this method should be better, no ?

Comment: A key check in php is fast, because it will check it once (php internal array stuff)! In array lookup has to check all values against the lookup (maybe casting values before checking too), until it was found. Make your benchmarks with big arrays (500.000+) and you will see.

Comment: I've won 20 millisecond in the page load. Thanks a lot for your answer ! Have a nice day

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Please post your helpful comment as an answer so that the question looks resolved, Baptiste can accept it, and future readers can quickly glean the vital wisdom from your advice without scanning through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is fine,

but better do 
`$array[$document->color->name]=true;`

and `if(!isset($array[$document->color->name]))`

bescause it is way faster then `in_array()` and you will not fill your array with useless dublicates.